# Android SecretKey to String and back

Tags: android, encryption, secret-key

I need to know how to generate a String of a SecretKey and convert it back into a SecretKey.

I first generated a SecretKey using the KeyGenerator like in the code below and I used it and it worked, but I also saved the SecretKey as a private value using getEncoded(). Now when I regenerate the SecretKey and use it in my code I get the error:

> W/System.err: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Unsupported key size: 43 bytes

I thought the following code should result in logging two equivalent Strings, but it does not.

```
                    KeyGenerator keyGen = null;
                    keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
                    keyGen.init(256);
                    SecretKey key= keygen.generateKey();

                    byte[] keyBytes = key.getEncoded();
                    SecretKey keyCopy = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

                    Log.d("key string: ", key.getEncoded().toString());
                    Log.d("keyCopy string: ", keyCopy.getEncoded().toString());
```

As per the comments I edited the above code from `byte[] keyBytes = key.getEncoded().toString().getBytes();` to `byte[] keyBytes = key.getEncoded();` removing redundancy.

Comment: In Java calling the `toString()` method on a byte array does not give useful information about the contents. `byte[] keyBytes= key.getEncoded()` makes sense, `byte[] keyBytes= key.getEncoded().toString().getBytes()` does not.

Comment: In general there is nothing superior about a String over a byte[]. If you are trying to "convert" a byte[] to a String you should be able to explain why. If it makes sense to do so then the answer is usually to base64 encode the byte array to get a String, and then base64 decode the String to get the back array back again. Sometimes hex-encoding is used instead of base64.

Comment: For my purposes I will be using a String made from a base64 encoded byte[], but currently even the byte arrays aren't returning equal values.

Comment: Assuming that the  ```toString()``` is returning a representation of the input without some other randomizing variable.

Comment: It doesn't, `[B.toString()`  returns an encoding of the type & reference, it doesn't contain any information about the actual value at all. Here `[B`  is the runtime type of the byte array.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have stated. `toString()` does not return a representation of the object itself, in this case, but something variable. While it returns values that differ for each byte array, encoding them into base65 using `Base64.encodeToString(key.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT)` results in equivalent representations of both the original key and its copy.

```
                KeyGenerator keyGen = null;
                keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
                keyGen.init(256);
                SecretKey key= keygen.generateKey();

                byte[] keyBytes = key.getEncoded();
                SecretKey keyCopy = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

                Log.d("key string: ", Base64.encodeToString(key.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                Log.d("keyCopy string: ", Base64.encodeToString(keyCopy.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT));
```